# Set cookies with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, session-cookies, nsurlsession

Hi I am developing one Iphone application In which I want to set cookies after server response and use that for another request. My network request looks like.

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
    NSLog(@"sttaus code %i", httpResp.statusCode);
    if (error) {
        [self.delegate signinWithError:error];
    }
    else {
        [self.delegate signinWithJson:data];
    }
}] resume];
```

But I don't know how to set cookies. I know I have to use `NSHTTPCookieStorage` but I don't know how to set. And I also want to use that cookies for another request. Is there any one who knows about this? Need help. Thank you.

See I tried in this way

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{      
    if(error) {
        [self.delegate signinWithError:error];
    }
    else {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;

        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
        NSHTTPCookie *cookie;

        NSMutableDictionary *cookieProperties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        NSDictionary* headers = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];

        for(NSString *key in [headers allKeys]) {
            NSLog(@"%@ ..PPPP ... %@",key ,[headers objectForKey:key]);
            [cookieProperties setObject:[headers objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
        }

        [cookieProperties setObject:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:2629743] forKey:NSHTTPCookieExpires];

        cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:cookieProperties];
        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];

        [self.delegate signinWithJson:data];
    }
}] resume];
```

I am interested in only one header field `Set-Cookie  SSID=kgu62c0fops35n6qbf12anqlo7; path=/`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can probably get away with just using the [`sharedHTTPCookieStorage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSHTTPCookieStorage/sharedHTTPCookieStorage) for [`NSHTTPCookieStorage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and then use [`setCookies:forURL:mainDocumentURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSHTTPCookieStorage/setCookies:forURL:mainDocumentURL:) or the single [`setCookie:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001703-CJBDADAC) - the latter might be better for your needs.

If this doesn't work you might need to setup the [`NSURLSessionConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLSessionConfiguration) and set the [`NSHTTPCookieStorage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/HTTPCookieStorage)

The docs don't state it, but the [`defaultSessionConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLSessionConfiguration/defaultSessionConfiguration) might use the shared store anyway.

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;

    NSArray *cookies = [NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:[response allHeaderFields] forURL:[response URL]];
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookies:cookies forURL:[response URL] mainDocumentURL:nil];

    NSLog(@"sttaus code %i", httpResp.statusCode);
    if (error) {
        [self.delegate signinWithError:error];
    }
    else {
        [self.delegate signinWithJson:data];
    }
}] resume];
```

Comment: I have header fields after login request. So I have two way to do this one add my session id (or require fields) into user's data or save it as cookies. I decided cookies to use. But I don't know how to create and how to pass cookies with NSURLSESSION .

Comment: Can you post the header fields please - feel free to remove important data

Comment: Ad you have the cookie in the response - I thought you wanted to set it on the request

Comment: :). See this is full scenario. User will login to my app. after login I have to maintain session for that user. So what I am doing once User logged in I am saving session id for some time. So if user do some activities in my app I need that session id. Otherwise server gives 401 error. So after login for any request I am passing that session id for authentication on sever side. Is this the correct way or there is better way. Happy to accept better one :)

Comment: There we go, try that - if that doesn't work you might need to use a custom session config, let me know

Comment: This will create cookie for me but how can I add this one into other request header. Is there any way by which my request can use cookies by default. I think there is one configuration. I am not sure. Is there any? In android cookie store is there. Is there any such thing for IOS.

Comment: Do the other requests have the same domain/path as the cookie is set on?

Comment: I am not interested in other part of cookies I am interested in session filed. `Set-Cookies` and its value

Comment: The other parts of the cookie are important - they define where the cookie can be used.

Comment: ok. But in android I use only session id and that works :). I am happy to send send all cookie part but don't know how to send with `NSURLSESSION`. And all request are in same domain.

Comment: I've already posted how to send cookies with `NSURLSession`. Even in android you still need to [set cookies against a URL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setCookie%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) (and `java.net.CookieStore` [is the same](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookieStore.html#add%28java.net.URI,%20java.net.HttpCookie%29)). Post your android code as well...

Comment: I don't have android code now will post it soon. And will try this one let you know whether works or not :)

Comment: Any requests that use the `sharedSession` will use the shared cookie store, so they will pick up any cookies that have a matching domain and path.

Comment: instead of saving all header field can I store only few values and use them ?

Comment: `cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:forURL:` extracts only the `Set-Cookie` headers. You can iterate through this list and pull out the ones you want to use, but you *still* need to set them against a URL. Unless you don't want to set any of the other cookies, you might as well just set them all

Comment: No, sorry. And I've done it multiple ways - using cookies, Oauth, session tokens, basic auth. This method should work for what you wan to do.

Answer (score -10):

I researched a lot but found one in a website of another language. The solution is to add an empty event handler for session start and end:

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you answered the wrong question here by mistake or what, but this answer is absolutely unrelated to the question.