# Set Cookies to HTTP POST Requests from Swift NSURLSession

Tags: swift, post, cookies

I'm trying to use the below code but it doesn't work! Any Idea

```
    let jar = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()

    let cookieHeaderField = ["Cookie": self.CookieValue] // var CookieValue = String()
    let url = URL
    let parameters = ""
    let postData:NSData = parameters.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

    let cookies = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(cookieHeaderField, forURL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    jar.setCookies(cookies, forURL: NSURL(string: url), mainDocumentURL: NSURL(string: url))
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = postData
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set cookies with NSURLSession](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218242/set-cookies-with-nsurlsession)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218242/set-cookies-with-nsurlsession and just use the swift calls instead of objective-C.

Comment: I don't know how to work with objective C

Comment: Visit here for right answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590992/swift-how-to-set-cookie-in-nsmutableurlrequest

Answer (score 1):

try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218242/set-cookies-with-nsurlsession) for setting cookies and for better usage understanding.

Below is the swift part for setting up cookie.

```
let cookies = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(response.allHeaderFields as NSDictionary as! [String : String], forURL: response.URL!)

NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().setCookies(cookies, forURL: response.URL!, mainDocumentURL: nil)
```